# Does this sum of two Euler products converge for $s=1$?

Tags: number-theory, convergence-divergence, euler-product

The following sum of two Euler products is always real for real $s$:

$$A(s):=\prod_{p=prime} (1 - (i\,p)^{-s})^{-1}+\prod_{p=prime} (1 - (-i\,p)^{-s})^{-1}$$

**ADDED:**

Some (trivial) closed forms that I found so far:

$A(2) = \frac{4}{5}\zeta(2)$

$A(4) = 2\,\zeta(4)$

$A(6) = \dfrac{2\,\zeta(12)}{\zeta(6)}$

$A(8) = 2\,\zeta(8)$

$A(10) = \dfrac{2\,\zeta(20)}{\zeta(10)}$

$A(12) = 2\,\zeta(12)$

$A(14) = \dfrac{2\,\zeta(28)}{\zeta(14)}$

$A(16) = 2\,\zeta(16)$

$\cdots$

Numerical evidence suggests that this sum also converges at $s=1$ (edit: I used $\lim_{s\to 1^+}$), albeit slowly. Could this be proven/falsified ?

Comment: This seems like a pretty hard question to me. This is asking for something like the behavior or partial sums $\sum_{n \leq N} (-i)^{\Omega(n)}$, where $\Omega(n)$ is the number of prime divisors of $n$ with multiplicity. I guess you're really asking about $\sum_{n \leq N, \Omega(n) \equiv 0 \bmod 2} (-1)^{\Omega(n)/2}$. This is asking about the distribution of numbers of divisors (mod $4$). I would guess that it does converge, but this might not be currently provable (though this is a bit out of my typical area).

Comment: @davidlowryduda Thanks for your response. It seems pretty hard indeed. I have added some of the trivial closed forms at even integers, however have not found any for the odd integers yet.

Comment: As it is your question doesn't make sense, edit to make clear what **limit** you are considering.

Comment: @Agno Did you want $i$ to be raised to the power $s$ in the Euler products $$A(s):=\prod_{p=prime} \left(1 - \frac{i^{-s}}{p^s}\right)^{-1} + \prod_{p=prime} \left(1 -\frac{(-i)^{-s}}{p^s}\right)^{-1}?$$
Typically in an Euler product or Dirichlet series, the coefficients in the product or sum have no dependence on $s$. I'm wondering if this question was supposed to be about the superficially similar $$A^*(s):=\prod_{p=prime} \left(1 - \frac{i}{p^s} \right)^{-1} + \prod_{p=prime} \left(1 -\frac{(-i)}{p^s}\right)^{-1},$$ which would have the Dirichlet series David's comment was referencing.

Comment: Your "trivial" cases are represented by $$ A(2n) = 2 \: \zeta(2n)^{\cos(\pi n)} \zeta(4n)^{\sin^2(\frac{\pi n}{2} )} $$

Comment: @Rivers McForge No, I was not referring to the Euler product of a Dirichlet series.

Comment: @reuns Updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The boring/trivial answer is no

$A: \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{C}$ doesn't converge at $x = 1$ in its original definition $$A(x):=\prod_{p \, \text{prime}} (1 - (i\,p)^{-x})^{-1}+\prod_{p \, \text{prime}} (1 - (-i\,p)^{-x})^{-1}$$ because the individual products $F(x) := \prod_{p \, \text{prime}} (1 - (i\,p)^{-x})^{-1}$ and $\overline{F(x)} := \prod_{p \, \text{prime}} (1 - (-i\,p)^{-x})^{-1}$ don't converge at $x = 1$. This can pretty easily be checked via taking logs: $$\log F(x) = \sum_{p \, \text{prime}} \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{i^{nx}}{n p^{nx}} \sim \sum_{p \, \text{prime}} \frac{i}{p} + \mathcal{O}(1) \text{ as } x \to 1, $$ and we know $\sum_{p \, \text{prime}} \frac{i}{p}$ is divergent. Clearly the product $\overline{F(x)}$ converges at $x = 1$ iff $F(x)$ does.

### The interesting answer is also no

Since we're on the real axis, $A(x) = F(x) + \overline{F(x)} = 2 \operatorname{Re}(F(x))$. Even though $F$ and $\overline{F}$ diverge as $x \to 1^+$, we might surmise that the divergence happens "mostly" in the imaginary part, and cancelling that out leaves a real part that converges. Indeed (and this will be relevant shortly), we can show that $\lim_{x \to 1^+} |F(x)| = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{15}}$ despite the fact that $\lim_{x \to 1^+} F(x)$ DNE by an analogous method, because
\begin{align*}
|F(x)|^2 &= F(x) \overline{F(x)} \\
 &= \prod_{p \, \text{prime}} \left(1 - \frac{i^{-x}}{p^x}\right)^{-1} \left(1 - \frac{i^{x}}{p^x}\right)^{-1} \\
 &= \prod_{p \, \text{prime}} \left(1 - \frac{2 \cos( \pi x/2)}{p^x} + \frac{1}{p^{2x}}\right)^{-1} \\
 &\to \prod_{p \, \text{prime}} \left(1 + \frac{1}{p^{2}}\right)^{-1} =  \frac{\pi^2}{15} \text{ as } x \to 1^+. \
\end{align*}

The final step (demonstrating the stated convergence as $x \to 1^+$) requires us to argue that $$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \cos( \pi x/2) P(x) = 0,$$ where $P(x)$ is the [prime zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_zeta_function). As $x \to 1^+$, $P(x) \sim \ln (x-1)$, while $\cos(\pi x/2) \sim -(x-1)$, and so we can replace these two complicated functions with their simpler asymptotic equivalents and use L'Hopital to demonstrate that this limit is, in fact, zero.

#### Why is this relevant?

We know that $\lim_{x \to 1^+} |F(x)| = \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{15}}$ despite the fact that $\lim_{x \to 1^+} F(x)$ does not exist.

The OP's question asks if $\lim_{x \to 1^+} A(x) = \lim_{x \to 1^+} 2 \operatorname{Re}(F(x))$ exists.

But if $\lim_{x \to 1^+} |F(x)|$ and $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \operatorname{Re}(F(x))$ both existed, then so would $\lim_{x \to 1^+} F(x)$. Therefore, since $\lim_{x \to 1^+} F(x)$ does not exist, neither does $\lim_{x \to 1^+} A(x)$.

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer!

Comment: @Agno There are several problems in this answer. We need the $o(1)$ remainder, $O(1)$ is not enough. And I don't see how $\lim_{x \to 1^+} \cos( \pi x/2) P(x) $ is relevant.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \quad\prod_{p\le x} \frac1{1 +i p^{-1}}+\prod_{p\le x} \frac1{1 -i p^{-1}}$$ diverges, this follows immediately from Mertens thoerem $$\sum_{p\le x} p^{-1}=\log \log x+M+o(1)$$ so that $$\sum_{p\le x} \log(1+ip^{-1})=i\log \log x+a+ib+o(1)$$

$$\prod_{p\le x} \frac1{1 +i p^{-1}}+\prod_{p\le x} \frac1{1 -i p^{-1}}=2 e^{-a} \cos(b+\log\log x)+o(1) $$

Then $$\lim_{s\to 1^+} \Re(\prod_p \frac1{1 -e^{-i\pi s/2}  p^{-s}})$$ diverges as well, this is because as $s\to 1^+$,
$$-\sum_p \log(1 -e^{i\pi s/2}  p^{-s})= C+o(1)+e^{-i\pi s/2} \log \zeta(s)= C+o(1)+i\log (s-1) $$
$$\Re(\prod_p \frac1{1 -e^{i\pi s/2}  p^{-s}})=e^{\Re(C)} \cos(\Im(C)+\log(s-1))+o(1)$$

Comment: Thanks reuns. Hope you don't mind that I have accepted Rivers' broader answer.